# GRUB menu lists both Windows and Linux, but Linux won't boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I recently installed Windows on a separate partition, and I have elementary OS already installed on my PC. So I want to dual boot.

I have followed this link to install GRUB again:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7

Now both Windows and elementary OS are listed on GRUB menu, but Linux won't boot when I choose it. It boots in emergency mode with error:

```
[     3.662228] Couldn't get size:0x800000000000e
you are in emergency mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default"  or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance.
(or press Control-D to continue): _
```

Is my system corrupted or Linux GRUB not installed correctly?

Comment: Is that the complete error message you see? If not, can you please edit your question adding the whole text?

Comment: it's the complete error I see. followed by you are in emergency mode. to reboot type systemctl-reboot and so...

Comment: Please show the full text.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I have updated the post

Comment: What happens if you press Control-D or Enter? To make any educated guess we would probably need to know, as a start, your OS version, if your system is BIOS or UEFI based and your partitions list.

Comment: if I press Control+D or enter it open terminal. I'm running Elementary Juno OS and Windows 10 both in UEFI mode. Secure boot was enabled on installation but I disabled it now, don't know if it's relevant or not.

Comment: The most upvoted answer to the AU question you mentioned seems to be about BIOS systems. Since you are on a UEFI system you should probably follow the advice from [the possible duplicate linked there](https://askubuntu.com/q/88384/882661). (Also, please edit your question instead of adding information in comments. It improves readability (and comments are rather ephemeral)).

Comment: What was the result, when you typed `journalctl -xb`?